# Android MarshMallow MediaPlayer cuts off too soon

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have been having an issues playing audio files using `MediaPlayer` on *MarshMallow* where it stops too soon like a second or so.

The audio file is a *.wav* file with a length just under 3 seconds. It has the following properties:

- Codec: PCM S16 LE(araw)
- Channels: Mono
- Sample rate: 8000 Hz
- Bit per sample: 16

I have had this issue on the following devices:

- **OnePlus One** - *Android version:6.0.1*
- **Nexus 6** - *Android version:6.0.1*
- **Nexus 5** - *Android version:6.0.1*

The same code works on previous versions of Android.

From initial looks it looks due to the implementation of `NuPlayer` and the removal of `AwesomePlayer`. In *Lollipop* it was optional in developer settings to use `NuPlayer`.

Has anyone experienced this? what did you do to fix this?

My code put simply does the following:

```
String mAudioFilePath = "path to audio file"
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setWakeMode(getActivity(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
player.reset();
player.setDataSource(mAudioFilePath);
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    mp.start();
                                    audioSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                                    audioSeekBar.setMax(100);
                                    updateProgressBar();

                                }
                            });
player.prepareAsync();
```

`updateProgressBar()` - updates the `audioSeekBar` and is stopped from updating the `SeekBar` using:

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                audioSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                audioSeekBar.setMax(100);
                player.stop();
                player.reset();

            }
});
```

I get the following stack-trace:

```
05-01 18:53:18.344 31287-31287/? D/LockScreen: [ChargingTimeHelper] skip updating, mPreLevel: 71, curLevel: 71
05-01 18:53:23.582 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
05-01 18:53:23.593 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xb5f77600)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
05-01 18:53:23.593 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? W/msm8974_platform: Codec backend bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? I/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 15, path =  0
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE


                                              [ 05-01 18:53:23.594  7326: 7441 D/         ]
                                              Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F 
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_VOL_CAL
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE


                                              [ 05-01 18:53:23.594  7326: 7441 D/         ]
                                              Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F 
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
05-01 18:53:23.594 7326-7441/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
05-01 18:53:23.601 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
05-01 18:53:23.604 7326-7052/? I/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xaeaf9240
05-01 18:53:23.605 7326-7052/? D/FFmpegExtractor: suppoted codec(pcm_s16le) by official Stagefright
05-01 18:53:23.605 7326-7052/? D/FFmpegExtractor: ffmpeg detected media content as 'audio/x-wav' with confidence 0.08
05-01 18:53:23.607 7326-7051/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb5f26b60), (1, 0, 0)
05-01 18:53:23.611 7326-7447/? D/NuPlayerDriver: start(0xb5f26b60), state is 4, eos is 0
05-01 18:53:23.611 7326-7051/? I/GenericSource: start
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: pfmt: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: inpS: (int32_t) 32768
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 0
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/AudioPolicyManagerCustom: PCM offload property is enabled
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/AVNuUtils: No channel mask, try channel count
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? W/AVNuUtils: No bitrate info
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/NuPlayer: canOffloadDecodedPCMStream
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/AVNuUtils: decision 0 mime audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.612 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/AudioPolicyManagerCustom: PCM offload property is enabled
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/NuPlayer: PCM offload decided: 0
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: pfmt: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: inpS: (int32_t) 32768
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 0
05-01 18:53:23.613 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/AudioPolicyManagerCustom: PCM offload property is enabled
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/AVNuUtils: No channel mask, try channel count
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? W/AVNuUtils: No bitrate info
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/NuPlayer: canOffloadDecodedPCMStream
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/AVNuUtils: decision 0 mime audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: srte: (int32_t) 8000
05-01 18:53:23.614 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: sbit: (int32_t) 16
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: mime: (char*) audio/raw
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: dura: (int64_t) 2950000
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: chnm: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/MetaData: #chn: (int32_t) 1
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/AudioPolicyManagerCustom: PCM offload property is enabled
05-01 18:53:23.615 7326-7051/? I/NuPlayer: PCM offload decided: 0
05-01 18:53:23.621 7326-7055/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(53:google.raw.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
05-01 18:53:23.621 7326-7055/? I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
05-01 18:53:23.622 7326-7055/? I/MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode
05-01 18:53:23.687 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
05-01 18:53:23.688 7326-7051/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb5f26b60), (6, 0, 0)
05-01 18:53:23.688 7326-7054/? I/NuPlayerDecoder: [audio] saw output EOS
05-01 18:53:24.314 5072-5286/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
05-01 18:53:24.315 31287-31287/? D/LockScreen: [BatteryInfoTracker] Received: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
05-01 18:53:24.315 31287-31287/? D/LockScreen: [ChargingTimeHelper] update charging, scale: 100, mPreLevel: 71, curLevel: 71, mPreTime: 66930510, curTime: 67110512, plug: 2, mStatsStarted: true
05-01 18:53:24.315 31287-31287/? D/LockScreen: [ChargingTimeHelper] skip updating, mPreLevel: 71, curLevel: 71
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7053/? E/NuPlayerRenderer: CHECK_EQ(copy mAudioSink->frameSize(), 0) failed b/25372978
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7053/? E/NuPlayerRenderer: mAudioSink->frameSize() 2
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7053/? E/NuPlayerRenderer: bytes to copy 14431
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7053/? E/NuPlayerRenderer: entry size 14431, entry offset 0
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7051/? E/NuPlayer: audio track encountered an error (-2147483648)
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7051/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb5f26b60), (100, 1, -2147483648)
05-01 18:53:25.440 7326-7051/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb5f26b60), (2, 0, 0)
05-01 18:53:25.440 4711-4726/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
05-01 18:53:25.440 4711-4711/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
05-01 18:53:25.442 7326-7447/? D/NuPlayerDriver: stop(0xb5f26b60)
05-01 18:53:25.442 7326-7447/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb5f26b60), (8, 0, 0)
05-01 18:53:25.442 7326-7448/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xb5f26b60)
05-01 18:53:25.446 7326-7051/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyResetComplete(0xb5f26b60)
05-01 18:53:25.447 7326-7326/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xb5f26b60)
05-01 18:53:28.446 7326-7441/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xb5f77600) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated